# How is caching POST requests done in REST architecture?

Tags: rest

Inside: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

There's this sentence that got me wondering: "The GET and POST methods are cacheable, meaning that responses to them are allowed to be stored for future reuse."

Caching something that is fetched using GET seems obvious since it fetches a static document.

But what sense is there in caching POST requests if it would seem that each will be different? What are some use cases that this would make sense?

Comment: It would be highly subjective (making this question not very suitable for StackOverflow) but I can think of some instances where you might want to cache a POST response. A [search engine request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) with a POST request payload for example

Answer (score 3):

The [IANA method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) currently lists [draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.3) as the authoritative reference for POST:

> Responses to POST requests are only cacheable when they include explicit freshness information (see [Section 4.2.1 of [CACHING]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19#section-4.2.1)) and a Content-Location header field that has the same value as the POST's target URI ([Section 8.7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-8.7)).  A cached POST response can be reused to satisfy a later GET or HEAD request, but not a POST request, since POST is required to be written through to the origin server, because it is unsafe; see Section 4 of [CACHING].

Using the Content-Location header in this way is how we indicate that the payload of the response is a representation of the target resource, as opposed to being any arbitrary status of the action.

---

> What are some use cases that this would make sense?

Any time POST is being used to modify the target resource

```
GET /the-car
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{ "color" : "red" }
```

```
POST /the-car
Content-Type: text/plain

Bob, the car should be blue, can you fix that please?
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Location: /the-car

{ "color" : "blue" }
```

Comment: This is good. What I would add to the example: 1) Make it absolutely clear that caching that last response means that it's potentially usable as a response to `GET /the-car`, and 2) Add `Cache-Control` or something to satisfy the requirement for "explicit freshness information".